# Pipe viewer not working with mysql

Tags: bash, ssh, pv

I have a new web hosting server (Ubuntu 20) that I need to manage over ssh (shell is bash).

It has this strange issue that `pv` does not print anything when piping to `mysql`.

I.e.

`gunzip < mydump.sql.gz | pv | mysql -u local -p*** db_name`

just shows blinking cursor, and only prints the `pv` stuff when aborted with Ctrl+C.

If I take `mysql` out of the picture then `pv` starts working:

`gunzip < mydump.sql.gz | pv | cat > /dev/null`

This prints progress as expected.

I would appreciate any insight on this matter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe you can try something more strait, like `gzip -dc mydump.sql.gz | mysql -u local -p*** db_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that the server is rather slow (throttled) and the reason for `pv` not print anything was that `mysql` froze at start-up, probably trying to load table list or something, thile the disk I/O queue was full.